# Getting objects by type in TypeScript with AMD loading

Tags: typescript, amd

I'm trying to loop through an `array` and genericly grab an item I want. At first I did this:

```
  getItemsByType<T>(type: string): T[] {
     var results: T[] = [];
     for (var item in this) {
        if (typeof this[item] === type) {
           results.push(this[item]);
        }
     }
     return results;
  }
```

However my Foo() class is just returned as typeof object.

```
  getItemsByType<T>(type: string): T[] {
     var results: T[] = [];
     for (var item in this) {
        if (this[item] instanceof type) {
           results.push(this[item]);
        }
     }
     return results;
  }
```

This just doesn't work, I cannot use `instanceof` without an actual `class`. However I am using an `AMD` loader (`dojo`), so cannot don't have an easily accessible constructor from this lonely method.

In my specific instance I have an array of base type, with many classes inheriting from it for their definitions. So later I need to pull a specific type from it. If this isn't possible I may need to start storing by type aswell.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript types don't survive the compilation process - they are erased, so all your modules and classes are objects at runtime.

This means you need to resort to [JavaScript to get the name of the object at runtime](http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201304/Blog/Obtaining-A-Class-Name-At-Runtime-In-TypeScript/) (or pop a property on each class that tells you its type).

The example below is taken directly from the article and the caveats are that you only get the local name - you don't know the full path (for example Module.Module.ClassName):

```
class Describer {
    static getName(inputClass) { 
        var funcNameRegex = /function (.{1,})\(/;
        var results = (funcNameRegex).exec((<any> inputClass).constructor.toString());
        return (results && results.length > 1) ? results[1] : "";
    }
}
class Example {
}
class AnotherClass extends Example {
}
var x = new Example();
var y = new AnotherClass();
alert(Describer.getName(x)); // Example
alert(Describer.getName(y)); // AnotherClass
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
interface NewableClass { new(); }

getItemsByType<T extends NewableClass>(type: T): T[] {
     var results: T[] = [];
     for (var item in this) {
        if (this.hasOwnProperty(item) && this[item] instanceof type) {
           results.push(this[item]);
        }
     }
     return results;
}
```

It specifies that `type` must be something that is "newable".  When using a dijit as type, for example, you will use it like `xxx.getItemsByType(dijit.form.TextBox);`

If you don't want to create a new interface, you can also do:

```
getItemsByType<T extends Function>(type: T)
```

In JavaScript, a class is really a function.  The [LINQ-to-TypeScript](https://github.com/schungx/LINQ-to-TypeScript) project has the method `ofType` defined just this way.

Also, if you use Dojo, check out my [Dojo-TypeScript](https://github.com/schungx/Dojo-TypeScript) project.  It is a work in progress, but somewhat useable.

Comment: Also, notice ``hasOwnProperty`` which you forgot.  It is usually a good idea to pair this call inside a ``for ... in`` loop.